# c# Variable uses

Tags: c#, variables, declaration, variable-declaration

I using c# winforms and wanted to know how it's better to write and why.

```
if(txtName.Text == "John")
    ;
```

or

```
String name = txtName.Text
if (name == "John")
    ;
```

Edit: Thanks guys you helped me a lot!!!

Comment: You should use `.Equals()` when comparing strings.

Comment: @EvanMulawski: That's true for Java, but not for C#.

Comment: @dtb: It is still good practice.

Comment: Not really. With `.Equals` you have to check for null references before you make the call, while `==` will take care of this for you.

Comment: @EvanMulawski These kind of sentences should be done having some background... :)

Comment: @MatiasFidemraizer Actually, I have over six years experience with C#, as it was the first language I learned. I have always used Equals and have never run into any problems. In real programs (not test cases), you hardly ever run into the need to handle a null string - if the string is null, something went wrong, and the reason should be checked before utilizing the string value.

Comment: @EvanMulawski Honestly, quantity != quality. In C#, since its early versions, the recommended way to do equality checks is using _the equality operator_. Sure `.Equals` could be the same, but it's more a Java approach than a C# one. And I didn't tell you about "background" because of handle or not handle a null string. It's just because **your recommendation isn't in the right way**.

Comment: @EvanMulawski @MatiasFidemraizer I'd say it's a matter of personal preference, although I'd use `"John == text"` instead of the other way around since you can't assign string constants by mistake. And on the topic of Equals, use Object.Equals ([the static one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx)) instead, it's awesome for readability, handles null values, and doesn't scare Java-devs. I mean, most developers have to program in many languages, and I've often found the best-effort method to be the most efficient in real life applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second version is pointless - it is longer, less readable and introduces one extra variable (though a good compiler would get rid of it, assuming it is not used elsewhere).

Of the two choices, this one is better:

```
if(txtName.Text == "John")
```

Though I would go with a third:

```
if(txtName.Text.Equals("John", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

You may want the [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) option to be a different enumeration value, depending on how you want the comparison to occur.

Comment: Why InvariantCulture and not CurrentUICulture?

Comment: @dtb - Why `CurrentUICulture` and not `InvariantCulture`?

Comment: `txtName.Text` contains user input from the UI. The UI is localized according to CurrentUICulture.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity sake I would go with:

```
if(txtName.Text.Equals("John"))
```

Comment: Why "Equals" in C#? Do you have any strong argument for that?

Comment: The static method `String.Equals` would make sense, but using instance-based `Equals` without a null-check could be hazardous since we do not know the exact context (winforms inits strings to null unless otherwise specified). If you use the instance-based string equals, do it the other way around: `if ("John".Equals(txtName.Text)) { CODE }`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm wrong, but others are answering to some complex scenario which isn't the case of one suggested by OP.

What's better?

In fact, it's the same. There's a single difference: first approach, you're storing control's text in a variable and later you check if it's equal to John. Second approach does the same thing, but it gets control's text accessing its string value directly by calling `Text` property.

When to use a variable and when to access to the property directly? It's just an assumption, because this will depend on each particular use case, but in common terms, *call `Text` property directly if you're accessing its object (the text) just for checking it in a moment of time*, otherwise, you'd want to store it in some variable if:

- If you want to do some concatenation with `Text` without affecting the text held by this (if you concatenate it to the `Text`, you're going to modify it in your app user interface too!).
- You're in a multi-threaded environment and you want to get `Text` in its current state because it can change since user interface is available to the user and it can change its value during some operation.
- **You just like variables!**. If you find using variables clarifies your code better and adds meaning, why not? Nowadays' computers, even mobile phones, have a lot of memory and one, two or three variables wouldn't change anything (maybe 1KB more? wohoo!).

That's all.

Comment: Thank you very much... I will keep all that in my mind

Answer (score 2):

Read [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121).

```
if (String.Equals(txtName.Text, "John", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
   // ...Code.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(txtName.Text == "John")
```

This is more conventional and efficient way of these you have shown.

```
String name = txtName.Text
if (name == "John")
    ;
```

Declaring extra variable "name"  will increase the code size with any benefit except increasing the program memory. Once I tried and found declaring extra variable and assigning text to it and later accessing this variable instead of text property txtName.Text makes it less efficient then accessing through property.

Answer (score 1):

For string comparison i would suggest:

```
string.compare(strA, strB, stringComparisonMethod)
```

For accessing the text it doesn't matter, the second way is more friendly but both will do the same

Answer (score 1):

I think the later is better because you will be using a less variable i.e. `name` . Except that I don't see any difference (the styling is obviously upto yourself)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the value in other parts of your code, I'd go with defining a variable. Otherwise, use the shorter version.

In C# you don't have to use .Equals to compare strings (in response to a comment). == does the same thing.